# Unity 3d scale plane to screen size

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to transfer my screen size to world size so I can scale my plane with the same ratio as my screen. But it just makes screen2World (0.0f,0.0f,0.0f)?

```
void Awake()
{
    Vector3 screen2World = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width,Screen.height,0.0f));
    background.localScale = new Vector3(screen2World.x,1.0f,screen2World.y);
    print(screen2World);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `z` you pass into the `ScreenToWorldPoint(...)` is the `z` distance from the camera. At `0f` the point will be directly in the middle, as the entire Frustum comes to a point at `0f`. Anything other than `0f` will give you a value.

```
public float distance = 100f;
void Awake()
{
    Vector3 screen2World = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width,Screen.height,distance));
    background.localScale = new Vector3(screen2World.x,1.0f,screen2World.y);
    print(screen2World);
}
```